# OnCheckedChangeListener is not working for the check box

Tags: android-actionbar, android-checkbox, oncheckedchanged

I am giving a check box to my action bar. this checkbox will be  used to select all the items of my listactivity. butsetOnCheckedChangeListener is not working for this check box. 
  I have created a seperate layout for my action bar and inflate it dynamically through java code.(in oncreate()).
  Below is my code for ListActivity: I have to also call the webservice on send button click in my custom layout of action bar. Please give me a solution if anyone have.

```
package com.logiquemantra.frapps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.logiquemantra.frapps.R;
import com.logiquemantra.frapps.adapter.ApplicationAdapter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity{

    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;
    CheckBox selectAll;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listofapps);
        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_app_share_action_bar, null);
        selectAll = (CheckBox)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        selectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked){

                    for(int i = 0 ; i<applist.size(); i++){
                        getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                }else{
                    for(int i = 0 ; i<applist.size(); i++){
                        getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });



    }

    /*@Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar 
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.share_app_info, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    } */

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this,R.layout.listofapps, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(AllAppsActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#000" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Applications" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        >
          <CheckBox android:id="@+id/selectAll"
              android:text="@string/selectall"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:checked="true"
              android:textColor="#fff"
              android:paddingRight="15dp"
              />

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/imageButton"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignRight="@id/selectAll"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
              android:background="@null"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now" 
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just met this problem. You can't get the CheckBox's view this way.

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_app_share_action_bar, null);
selectAll =  (CheckBox)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
```

You should change it to:

```
View mCustomView=getActionBar().getCustomView();
selectAll =  (CheckBox)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
```

I hope it can work for you.